# Are custom context menu accessible?

Tags: html, mouseevent, accessibility

When clicking on `<tr>` in my table I would like to display the available operations on the record instead of an additional "actions" column.

Are custom context menus considered accessible according to the accessibility standards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to render a context menu in an accessible way.  It may create a little extra work.

From [Web Accessibility: "Standalone, attached, and context menus"](https://www.webaccessibility.com/best_practices.php?technology_platform_id=45)

> In the HTML specification, no component exists that allows developers to define either context or attached menus. Most often, developers implement menu functionality through a series of layers dynamically shown and positioned via JavaScript. This results in a menu system that is readily usable via the mouse, but can be difficult to use from the keyboard. Furthermore, accessing the menu structure involves significant client side content changes, which tend to be supported poorly in assistive technology.
>
> To address these issues, developers must ensure that attached menus are clearly indicated to the user and that all menus function properly from the keyboard. For principal elements that include attached menus, its textual representation should include a clear phrase such as "menu attached". This indicates to the user that an attached menu is present and it can be accessed in the standard fashion for the form. For form elements, this can be accomplished in the standard methods of explicit labeling, either via the title attribute or the label element. If a separate element is used to trigger the attached menu, the triggering element's textual representation should include the name of the principal element so that it is explicit what the menu relates to.

See the linked website for more details and guidelines on making context menus accessible.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - i read the article and understand that I need to handle focus and tab order. But, is the actual right click only access on its own a problem?

Comment: Yes.  Anything that's mouse-only is inherently not accessible to those who only use keyboards. "developers must ensure...that all menus function properly from the keyboard."

Comment: For an example of creating an accessible menu with ARIA markup, http://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Using_ARIA_menus (ARIA is a W3C standard for augmenting accessibility of interactive widgets)

Comment: Updated link:
https://www.webaccessibility.com/resource-library/platform/?platform=45

Answer (score 1):

**The best thing you could do is provide one additional button which will open the menu**.

This button has to be fully visible (for touchscreen, eye tracking devices), fully described (for screenreaders), and fully operational from both keyboard and mouse.

If there is no visual and explicit information that a click/keypress will open a menu that won't be accessible.

You could also add a "right click" event to the full `tr` to open the menu for fastest operation, but it should be used as a complement of the button, and more directed to ergonomy rather than accessibility.

Comment: [ARIA Navigation Menubar Example](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/examples/menubar/menubar-1/menubar-1.html#) also recommends the separate button approach. :+1

Comment: If you plan to implement the separate approach, remember to use the `<button>` element, not `<div>`, not `<a>` with CSS styled as a button. Using `<button` saves tons of work on the accessibility side. FYI, I [blogged](https://blog.junjizhi.com/all/technical/2020/08/17/a11y-nav-dropdown-menu.html) about this issue.